# Express.js URL Redirection Issue: How to Redirect Requests Based on Hostname and Path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-route53

I'm Working on a URL redirection project in node.js and express.js hosted on EC2.

In AWS Route53, I manage ten primary domains, each accompanied by various subdomains. Here's a brief overview:

1. **`test.com`** with subdomains like **`app.test.com`**, **`app2.test.com`**, and so on.
2. **`example.com`** with subdomains like **`redirect.example.com`**, **`help.example.com`**, and others.

These domains have **CNAME** records configured, pointing to a standard subdomain at **`subdomain.myorigindomain.com`**.

In my database, I maintain records that include the primary domain, the subdomain, a redirection string, and a destination. Additionally, I define a default destination for cases when a request lacks a specific path.

Below is my code to handle redirection:

```
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../client/build")));

app.get("*", async (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    try {
        
    var realUrl = (req.connection.encrypted ? "https" : "http") + "://" + req.headers.host + req.url;
    const Url = url.parse(realUrl, true);
    Url.remoteAddress = req.header("x-forwarded-for") || req.connection.remoteAddress;
    const redirectString = Url.path.substr(1);
       if(redirectString){
           //search into database and redirect to destinaton
         }else{
           //search subdomain and domain in database and redirect to default destination
         }
})
```

**The problem:**
Whenever a user sends a request from either the origin domain **`subdomain.myorigindomain.com`** or any primary domain, such as **`app.test.com`**, my frontend application is getting served using the following line of code:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../client/build")));`

When removed above mention line code then all request is handled by **`*`** and my front end not getting served for the origin domain **`subdomain.myorigindomain.com`**

**Expected behavior:**
Only when a user sends a request with my origin domain, specifically **`subdomain.myorigindomain.com`**, will my frontend application served.

In all other cases, such as requests from **`app.test.com`**, the routing will be handled by the **`*`** route.

**For Example:**
**Case 1:** When somebody hits **`app.test.com/help`** in the browser then it will go to **`*`** routes and search for **`/help` **in the database and redirect to its destination

**Case 2** When somebody hits **`app.test.com`** in the browser then request should be handled by **`*`** routes and it searches for the default URL of **`app.test.com`** and redirect to the default URL.

But in the above **Case 2** request is handled by the below line of code:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../client/build")));
```

and my front end getting served.

**Case 3:** When somebody hits my origin domain like **`subdomain.myorigindomain.com`** then it should only serve my frontend application.

**Here's what I've tried:**

Commented below line code:

```
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../client/build")));
```

Added a condition if the hostname is the same as the origin then redirect to frontend and send `index.html`  in     **`*`** route like below :

```
app.get("*", async (req, res) => {
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    try {
        
    var realUrl = (req.connection.encrypted ? "https" : "http") + "://" + req.headers.host + req.url;
    const Url = url.parse(realUrl, true);
    Url.remoteAddress = req.header("x-forwarded-for") || req.connection.remoteAddress;
if (Url.hostname === 'subdomain.myorigindomain.com' && (Url.pathname === '/' || Url.pathname === '/admin')) {
/** 
* I have tried below tried all below things
*  Method 1: return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../client/build/index.html"));
*  Method 2: 
*      res.set("location", `${configTable.origin}/admin`);
*      res.set("Cache-Control", "no-store");
*      return res.status(301).send();
*  Method 3: return res.redirect(`${configTable.origin}/admin`)
*  Method 4: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../client/build")));
*/
}
```

But nothing worked.
How I can fix the issue?

Comment: What is `Url` supposed to be? Details of the request can be found in `req` not floating around as random globals.

Comment: Hey @Quentin, yes all the details are in req but I am just parsing the request using url.parse() method.

Comment: You aren't here: ```app.get("*", async (req, res) => {
if (Url.hostname```

Comment: The preferred approach for that, BTW, is: ```const url = new URL(`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}${req.originalUrl}`);```

Comment: Agreed, but that is not an issue in my case when I am testing with any primary domain like **app.test/help**  then everything works fine and redirects to the destination if help is found in the database otherwise my else part works, and redirects to default destination.

Comment: when i am testing with **app.test.com** only then my front end getting serve and request is not going to `app.get("*" , async (req,res) =>`